# QR - Factorization: If A has full rank then R has non-zeros in the diagonal

Tags: matrices, numerical-linear-algebra, matrix-decomposition, matrix-rank

$Q$ is an orthogonal matrix. $R$ is an upper triangular matrix. $A \in \mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$ with $m > n$ and its QR-Factorizations is $A = QR$. Show that if $A$ has full rank, then the diagonal elements of $R$ are non-zero. Show also that the first $n$ columns of $Q$ are an orthonormal basis of the column space of $A$.

I tried to prove that, but with no success. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: if $R$ is upper triangular and $R_{kk} = 0$, then its first $k$ columns must be linearly dependent, which makes $R$ have rank $< n$.

By "the spanning of $A$" you mean "the column space of $A$", i.e. the span of the columns of $A$.

Comment: Yes, I meant column space. I edited that, thanks.

I don't quite understand why when the diagonal of $R$ has zeros then the first $k$ columns must be linearly dependent? Also even if this is true and $R$  has rank $< n$, how does this prove the rank of $A$?

Comment: 1) If $R_{kk} = 0$, the first $k$ columns of $R$ can have nonzero entries only in the first $k-1$ positions, and so are in the span of the vectors $e_1, \ldots e_{k-1}$ (where $e_j$ is the unit vector with $1$ in position $j$ and $0$ everywhere else).
Thus their span has dimension $\le k-1$.  
2) If $Rv = 0$ then $QRv = 0$.

Comment: @RobertIsrael If R has k non zero diagonal entries; then how to prove that k<rank(A)<n-1, If that's true?

Answer (score 1):

The column space of the matrix $A$ is the span of the columns. I.e

$$ \textrm{Span}(A) = \bigg\{ \sum_{i=1}^{n} c_{i}a_{i}  | c_{i} \in \mathbf{K} , a_{i} \in A \bigg\} $$

or any linear combination of the columns $a_{i}$. Now the columns $q_{i}$ are formed by iteratively subtracting of the previous projections.

$$ q_{n} = \frac{a_{n} - \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} r_{in}q_{i}}{r_{nn}}$$

so $q_{n}$ is a linear combination of the columns of $A$. Note that

$$ v_{n} = a_{n} - \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} r_{in}q_{i} $$

is orthogonal and the coefficient $r_{nn}$ is actually $\| v_{n}\|$ which makes $q_{n}$ orthonormal.

Note: I think $\textrm{Span}(A)$ is a slight abuse of notation.